# Multipling dataframe column by float - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sequence

This is a piece of my dataframe called df:

```
       carrera   cinta1   cinta2
0          0.61  499.556  611.029
1         0.876  499.556  611.029
2         1.082  499.556  611.029
3         1.167  499.556  611.029
4         1.337    0.045  611.029
```

I need to mulitply the column 'carrera' by a float (in this case 0.2)

My dataframe comes from a list:

```
def calculo(self, datos):
        
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(datos)
        df2.columns = ['carrera', 'cinta1', 'cinta2']

        print(df2.dtypes)
```

Then I multiply the column by 0.2

```
df1 = df2['carrera']*0.2
print(df1)
```

This gives an error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

**SOLVED**

The data on the dataframe was an object type.
When defining the dataset I added the following:

```
  df2 = pd.DataFrame(datos, dtype=float)
```

Comment: too many brackets, try 0.2*ddd['carrera']

Comment: Is that `.` or comma?

Comment: I have tried just one bracket, but getting the same error @EzerK

Comment: Im sorry it is a . @A.Najafi

Comment: pd.read_clipboard()['carrera']*0.2   works for me so don't know what to tell you

Comment: Maybe its the version, what is your version of pandas? @EzerK

Comment: pandas           : 1.3.4 (think it's the newest)

Comment: Yep, same here... Im using VS Code, does it have something to do? @EzerK

Comment: don't think so, let me try a full script you can copy and pase

Comment: pd.DataFrame({'carrera': {0: 0.61, 1: 0.876, 2: 1.082, 3: 1.167, 4: 1.337},
 'cinta1': {0: 499.556, 1: 499.556, 2: 499.556, 3: 499.556, 4: 0.045},
 'cinta2': {0: 611.029, 1: 611.029, 2: 611.029, 3: 611.029, 4: 611.029}})['carrera']*0.2

Comment: It does work on a separate file copypasting your code... what on earth...

Comment: I have included in the question how I create the dataFrame, does it give a little more info? @EzerK